# Proving an identity for a special form of Riemann tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, curvature

I have a homework problem. Given that the Riemann tensor is
$$R_{abcd} = g_{ac}S_{bd} + g_{bd}S_{ac} - g_{ad}S_{bc} - g_{bc}S_{ad}$$
I have to show that
$$\text{For} \ N>3 \ , \ S_{ab;c} = S_{ac;b}$$

I used the second Bianchi identity $R_{ab[cd;e]} = 0$
to get
$$g_{ac}(S_{bd;e} - S_{be;d}) + g_{ad}(S_{be;c} - S_{bc;e}) + g_{ae}(S_{bc;d} - S_{bd;c}) \\ + g_{bc}(S_{ae;d} - S_{ad;e}) + g_{bd}(S_{ac;e} - S_{ae;c}) + g_{be}(S_{ad;c} - S_{ac;d}) = 0$$

Now I contract both sides with $g^{ac}$ to get
$$(N-3)(S_{bd;e}-S_{be;d}) + g^{ac}g_{bd}(S_{ac;e} - S_{ae;c}) + g^{ac}g_{be}(S_{ad;c} - S_{ac;d}) = 0$$

Only if I knew how to deal with the second and third terms, this problem is solved. Because for $N=2$, there is another identity given in a previous part which makes the LHS trivially 0.

I need help to argue that the three terms have to be individually zero and then $N \neq 3$, which will complete the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contract with $g^{bd}$. That will prove $g^{ac}(S_{ad;c} - S_{ac;d}) = 0$, so you can set the second and third terms to zero.

Comment: Did you figure this out now, or do you know if this question is from a book? I would like to have that book for practice, if such exists.

Comment: I figured it out reading your question sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The have three fee indices $b,d,e$ contract with $g^{bd}$ will left we only one index which easier to handled 
$$(N-3)g^{bd}(S_{bd;e}-S_{be;d}) + g^{ac}g_{bd}g^{bd}(S_{ac;e} - S_{ae;c}) + g^{ac}g_{be}g^{bd}(S_{ad;c} - S_{ac;d}) = 0\;,\\
\longrightarrow (N-3)g^{bd}(S_{bd;e}-S_{be;d}) + g^{ac}N(S_{ac;e} - S_{ae;c}) + g^{ac}\delta^d_e(S_{ad;c} - S_{ac;d}) = 0\;,\\
(N-3)g^{bd}(S_{bd;e}-S_{be;d}) + g^{ac}N(S_{ac;e} - S_{ae;c}) + g^{ac}(S_{ae;c} - S_{ac;e}) = 0\;,\\
((N-3)+N-1)g^{bd}(S_{bd;e}-S_{be;d})=0\;,\\
(2N-4)g^{bd}(S_{bd;e}-S_{be;d})=0\;,\\
(N-2)g^{bd}(S_{bd;e}-S_{be;d})=0\;.
$$In general $g^{bd}\neq 0$, so for $N > 3$ we have $S_{bd;e}=S_{be;d}\;.$

Comment: It seems you copied my answer but misunderstood the final step. You can't just divide out $g^{bd}$ because it's contracting something. But you can then go back to the previous equation and get rid of the second and third terms.

Comment: Yes, sorry but I'm lazy now.  I gave a half of credits to you but I'm lazy now. Sorry again.